# Making 250mL of 0.1M NaOH

Tags: home-experiment

I measured out approximately 1g of NaOH pellets . I then transfer it into a volumetric flask and transfer some amount of distilled water into the flask and dissolve the pellets before filling the volumetric flash to the mark (250ml).

Why i can't make sodium hydroxide by transferring a fixed volume (250ml) into the flask ?

Comment: I don’t get what you’re asking, could you clarify?

Comment: @Jan I'm trying to ask if it is possible to prepare a standard NaOH solution by dissolving an accurate amount of NaOH solid in a known volume of water and i think it's not possible , but I'm not sure why

Comment: Oh, so using a random beaker to mix a fixed weight of sodium hydroxide with a fixed volume of water, both determined separately?

Comment: @Jan both using a volumetric flask . Can I get the same result of concentration ? 1. If I add a small volume of water and mix it before adding it up to 250ml after dissolving . 2. If I add exact 250ml and mix it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a fixed volume of water to a volumetric flask (e.g. $\pu{250ml}$) and then attempt to add sodium hydroxide to dissolve, the resulting volume will no longer be $\pu{250ml}$. Depending on the salt you are dissolving, it can be larger or smaller but it will never be identical. Thus, your resulting solution will not have the molarity you think it has.

The recommended procedure is to add a solid, add enough water to dissolve it (but well less than the volume of the volumetric flask!) and then slowly add water until the line is reached. This means you know exactly how much solute you have added (in grams and thus moles) and also how much the volume of the solution is.